# Vaadin numeric field?

Tags: vaadin7

Is there a DoubleField or LongField Vaadin 7?  I see a TextField and PasswordField, so it sort of shocked me when I did not see fields for numeric types.  This seems so standard, especially since GWT has such fields under the hood, that I feel like I am missing something.

Also, there are some numeric field add-ons, but most of them say they don't support Vaadin 7, which leads me to believe there is some standard way to do it in Vaadin 7 already.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way either but I created my own with a custom `TextChangeListener`. Basically you override the method `textChange(TextChangeEvent event)` to check if the value is valid. If it's not valid then you delete it. Just be careful to adjust the cursor appropriately. I created a listener for integers (with max/mins), one for doubles, percentages, etc. Basically any kind of number validation you need. The tricky part is managing the cursor position. I wish I had some sample code to show you but I don't have it available on my current computer, but at least this should give you a running start.

Comment: Actually, when I checked the Vaadin directory yet again for "number", limiting myself to only UI components and Vaadin7, I found a few components that looked promising.  I am currently trying [numberfield7](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/numberfield7---numberfield7-add-on), to see how that works.  Just strikes me as weird that these common ideas are not present in Vaadin API when they are supported under the hood by GWT, thus my confusion.  Regardless, if numberfield7 works, I will report that here as my solution.

Comment: I think it comes down to how you validate, which could be highly customizable. Do you show an error message? If so where and how? Do you allow you only allow numbers in the integer fields? Are there any popups? For a password do you just show asterisks or do you show the last value entered? Basically the devil is in the details and it's very specific to your preferences and UI. I think that's why they have to the add-on library, for exactly this type of need. What surprises me is why there aren't more add-on modules for this. Maybe there just isn't enough demand...